# How to rename a field in mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I have a database in which the schema was originally set as follows;

```js
const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  supplier: {
    type: String,
    required: 'Supplier is required',
    ref: 'Supplier'
  },
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: 'Name is required'
  },
  price: {
    type: Number,
    required: 'Price is required'
  }
})
```

But now I want to rename the field `name` to `product` like so;

```js
const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  supplier: {
    type: String,
    required: 'Supplier is required',
    ref: 'Supplier'
  },
  product: {
    type: String,
    required: 'Product is required'
  },
  price: {
    type: Number,
    required: 'Price is required'
  }
})
```

The result I am getting from my client isn't updating to show the `product` instead of `name`;

Result:

```js
[
  {
    "_id": "5df7baa7acf4ed3897d8d4c9",
    "supplier": "Old Co Ltd",
    "name": "Small Woggle",
    "price": 6
  }
]
```

and finally here is my database where I populate the fields in mongoose;

```js
mongoose.connect(dbURI, (err, db) => {

  db.dropDatabase()

    .then(() => Product.create([{
      supplier: 'Old Co Ltd',
      product: 'Small Woggle',
      price: 6
    }]))
    .then(products => console.log(`${products.length} products created`))
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
    .finally(() => mongoose.connection.close())
})
```

Please help me to rename this field

Answer (score 2):

You can't just rename the field in your schema. You need to actually run an update.

Example:

```
productSchema.update({}, { $rename: { name: 'product' } }, { multi: true }, (err) => {
  if(err) { throw err; }
  console.log('complete');
});
```

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/rename/

Comment: Thanks mwilson but I must be running that code in the wrong file because it now gives me this error in the terminal when i add it to my models file;
```
TypeError: productSchema.update is not a function
```

Comment: productSchema.update(
              ^

TypeError: productSchema.update is not a function

Comment: I was taking a guess at your object was for your schema. You'll have to update that code with what works for you. Maybe it's `Product`?

Answer (score -1):

The answer above works, but I also found an alternative without adding anything to your code.

Just use the following steps like so;
1. In terminal run `mongod`
2. Navigate to db and drop database `db.dropDatabase()`
3. Then initialize your database by running `node` on the file.